# Replace where ever the Sales of the product < 20 with the mean of the the sales in the similar group for python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to impute the values of the column "Sales" in the dataframe Transactions (in Python). i.e. Replace where ever the Sales of the product  < 20  with the mean of the the sales of their corresponding category and brand.

For ex, my data is in the below structure :

```
Category,Brand,Sales
Food    , pp  , 100 
Food    , pp  , 200
Food    , pp  , 10
Cream   , xy  , 40
Cream   , xy  , 2
Cream   , xy  , 60
```

Sales in the 3rd row (for Food and pp) i.e 10 should be replaced by mean of all the sales in the group Food and PP i.e. 100 + 200 /2 = 150 [ excluding the 3rd  row containing the sales as 10] .
Same applies for the 5th row i.e 2 should be replaced by mean of sales of Cream and xy i.e. ( 60 +40)/2 = 50 [ excluding the 5th row ].

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `mean`s per group of filtered values with same size as original `df`, so is possible replace by condition by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = df.groupby(['Category','Brand'])['Sales'].transform(lambda x: x[x >= 20].mean())
df['Sales'] = np.where(df['Sales'] < 20, a, df['Sales'])
```

Alternative solution:

```
a = df[df['Sales']>= 20].groupby(['Category','Brand'])['Sales'].mean()
b = df.drop('Sales', 1).join(a, on=['Category','Brand'])['Sales']
df['Sales'] = np.where(df['Sales'] < 20, b, df['Sales'])
```

---

```
print (df)
  Category Brand  Sales
0     Food    pp    100
1     Food    pp    200
2     Food    pp    150
3    Cream    xy     40
4    Cream    xy     50
5    Cream    xy     60
```

Comment: That Worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this also,

```
df.loc[df['Sales']<20,'Sales']=np.NaN
df['Sales']=df.groupby(['Category'])['Sales'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Output

```
  Category Brand  Sales
0     Food    pp  100.0
1     Food    pp  200.0
2     Food    pp  150.0
3    Cream    xy   40.0
4    Cream    xy   50.0
5    Cream    xy   60.0
```